# cfhttp to the stats.ezhostingserver website not working

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following Updated code where I am trying to connect to the website using the username/password and siteid combination, i am passing all values using get method and trying to fetch cookie to authenticate and go ahead but somehow i am again getting redirected to the login screen

My Code

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/Login.aspx" resolveurl="true" redirect="false">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="ctl00$MPH$txtUserName" value="********">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="ctl00$MPH$txtPassword" value="********">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="ctl00$MPH$txtSiteId" value="*****">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
</cfhttp>
<cfset stm_cookies = cfhttp.responseHeader['Set-Cookie'] />
<cfset stm_temp = REReplace(stm_cookies, ";.*", "")>
<cfset stm_cookieName = listfirst(stm_temp,'=')>
<cfset stm_cookievalue = listlast(stm_temp,'=')>
<cfhttp method="get" url="https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/default.aspx" charset="utf-8" result="results" redirect="no">
    <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="#stm_cookieName#" value="#stm_cookievalue#">
</cfhttp>
<cfoutput>#results.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

But it is saying me object moved error

Comment: Please include the actual error message with your question. Do a dump of the `results` variable after the `cfhttp` call.

Comment: Perhaps we need to take a step back here and ask what it is you are trying to do? If you are trying to gather information from SmarterStats using ColdFusion then it would probably make more sense to use their web services that exposes that information for you. It looks like they are available from your host - https://stats.ezhostingserver.com/Services/Statistics.asmx

Comment: here is the screenshot http://gr-group.in/stats/index.cfm. i tried to use fiddler to pass username/password in the url but something is not right

Comment: Looks like it is not accepting your login attempt. I would recommend using the web services instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Could be because you are doing a `<cfhttp method="get"` and not `<cfhttp method="post"`, maybe the server will only allow login's from posts as if it was coming from a browser.